# How can i create a theme only with a title an thumbnail?

Tags: wordpress, themes, thumbnails

I wanna have a simple wordpress theme like this:
[image]

I created this in photoshop so i can show you.
How can i make this ? I just wanna have a Title and the posts shown as thumbnails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello you can learn wordpress design from here :-

http://codex.wordpress.org/Site_Design_and_Layout

or

http://rockablethemes.com/wordpress-themes-tutorials/

But i will suggest you to buy premium theme

http://themeforest.net/

or

search free theme from here

http://wordpress.org/themes/search.php?q=video

If you creating theme by own i will suggest you to ask exact problem where you stuck.

here is code which you need to add the code in index.php

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="post box">
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(215,152), array('class' => 'thumbnail')); ?></a>
</div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
    <div class="navigation">      
<?php posts_nav_link(' ','<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/prevl.png" alt="Next" border="0" class="left" align="right" />','<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/nextl.png" alt="Next" border="0" align="right"  class="right" />'); ?> </div>
     <?php endif; ?>
```

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

currentlly  wordpress requires some basic files to run..You need to edit them according to your desired theme.

1. Make a folder in `wp-content > themes > your folder`
2. put some necessory files like `header.php, footer .php , style.css, page.php`
3. You ned to edit them according to your desired styling,once done create `pages` from admin panel and enjoy!

Comment: First create your website in `HTML`
then break its components like Header in `header.php` same as the `css` in `style.css`.